# Google sign-in URI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-signin

I'm coding from my garage, already deployed a GCloud Function, but don't have a corporate website yet. So my application origin URI is `localhost:###` so far. Now I want to integrate my web project with my GCF, following [Integrating Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in?refresh=1) I'm stuck because I just don't have a registered website for origin URI

Is an official website URI required to proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a URI is required. On top of that it needs to be HTTPS, which requires an SSL certificate. The exception is testing with localhost.

The reason is that when you use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate a user, the user goes to Google Accounts and authenticates. Then Google Accounts calls your `callback` URL to give you a token. This is part of the security design. If you could leave this blank, then the authentication chain would be broken. I am oversimplifying OAuth 2.0 in this answer.

You could use Google App Engine, which then provides you with a URL for your deployment. App Engine will work as your orgin and callback.

[App Engine User Authentication Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/)

If your goal is to use Compute Engine, then you will need both a domain name and SSL certificate (Let's Encrypt is free) for your webserver.

Comment: 1) Can you elaborate more on "exception is testing localhost"? 2) My design is client = browsers + mobile app, they talk to a "backend" webserver piece like IIS/Apache servicing requests involving some GCF utilizing Vision and Pub/Sub, guess App Engine can be this "backend" piece?

Comment: localhost means running a web server on your develoment machine for testing and development. Google relaxes some rules such as requring HTTPS. In this context localhost is the same system that is running the web browser for authentication with Google Accounts. The redirect happens on the same machine to 127.0.0.1. IIS/Apache/App Engine is your backend. A desktop web browser, iOS, Android are your clients. However, in this example, back-end also means front-end as you are not splitting your server infrastructure (such as Cloud Storage, SQL database, etc).

Comment: Right, to Google's own GCF, IIS/App Engine are also appear as front-end. And good point you have that things like storage/SQL should be located/integrated as near as possible to AppEngine to avoid such as latency. Google's document is so scattered and dry. I like reading plain English such as yours, this is the highest level of lecturing. Do you have an article or link on how to develop and test using `localhost` before having a `https://aDomain.com`?

Comment: No articles on this yet, but I have lots of sample code in Python. I have a blog site that I publish articles on. I did publish an article on using `curl` for OAuth on my site. I will write an article or two on using Python, C# for OAuth maybe this weekend and include working code https://www.jhanley.com